# SSIS package to update SQL table

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have a file that contains Client information (client number, client name, client type, etc.) and I imported that into a SQL table.

Client information can change, and when it changes it changes it in the file.

Now, what I want to do is create a SSIS package that will read the file and search for any differences between the file and SQL table and if any changes are picked up, it needs to update the table according to the file (the file will always contain the latest information).

How would I achieve this? Is this possible from an SSIS perspective?

Comment: Please read the "How to ask" page: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: google "SSIS file upsert"

Answer (score 1):

There's different option to achieve it.

1. Load the file initially in a Stage Table and merge that into production table, it will insert data if it do not match and if it match than you can update the production table accordingly. Get more info on - https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1704/using-merge-in-sql-server-to-insert-update-and-delete-at-the-same-time/
2. Load the data into Stage table than use [lookup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/data-flow/transformations/lookup-transformation?view=sql-server-2017) transformation in SSIS to achieve it. Find the link for lookup transformation -  [https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/ssis/implementing-lookup-logic-in-sql-server-integration-services/](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/data-flow/transformations/lookup-transformation?view=sql-server-2017)